# Fortran INTENT attribute with an actual argument with vector subscript

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

[Intel's documentation about the `intent` attribute](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-oneapi-dev-guide-and-reference/top/language-reference/a-to-z-reference/h-to-i/intent.html) says

> If an actual argument is an array section with a vector subscript, it cannot be associated with a dummy array that is defined or redefined (has intent OUT or INOUT).

How should I understand the description?

Does it mean that the following code is wrong?

```
subroutine sub(a)
    real, intent(out) :: a(:)
end subroutine sub

real :: arr(3,4)
call sub(arr(1,:))
```

Comment: @francescalus The link is updated. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is fine, it is an array section rather than a vector subscript. The latter is where you use a rank one integer array expression for the subscripts. Extending your example:

```
subroutine sub(a)
    real, intent(out) :: a(:)
end subroutine sub

real :: arr(3,4)
call sub(arr(1,:))           ! Legal
call sub(arr(1,[ 1, 2, 4 ] ) ! Illegal
```